# liquibase comments in sql formatted changelogs

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, liquibase

I have a requirement to retain Oracle SQL comments made inside my Liquibase sql formatted changelogs. Thus I have the following attribute set  `stripComments:false`

Such comments in my SQL formatted changelogs are typically supplied using the standard -- (hyphen hyphen) characters

```
-- DROP LINK
```

However, it appears that with Liquibase attempts to execute all comments, and in this example, the comment above. This causes my Liquibase update to fail with the following error:

```
Invalid SQL type: sqlKind = UNINITIALIZED
```

I have tried to replcae all occurances of `-- comment` with `/* comment */` but this also generates the same error.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can check out [`StringUtils`](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/util/StringUtils.java)'s `stripComments()` method for how liquibase identifies comments in your SQL.

There are regex patterns defined for this:

1. `"\\s*\\-\\-.*\\n"`
2. `"\\s*\\-\\-.*$"`
3. `"/\\*.*?\\*/"`

You could take those patterns and put it in some online regex page (e.g. https://regex101.com/) along with your SQLs and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Any luck with the solution for this?

Comment: Dunno. It was just a suggestion. Guess you would need to as user2402135 what he/she ended up doing.